# Auto choosing form selection based on user interaction

Tags: forms, user-behavior

I am working with a group on revising their website and in one of the sections for a new facility, there is a form for the days of the week and hours of operations.

They also have a drop down choice to set the row to Open or Closed for that day. I am advocating for setting that choice to open automatically when a user begins entering hours into one of the daily slots.

Others are worried that we will be deciding user intent and it should not be done.

I'm wondering if this should be considered a helpful, time saving function or if it could be considered intrusive on user choice.

If you have any links to UX articles or research, that would be very helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Let user (analytics) data show you the appropriate state.**

You can initially set a default (based on your understanding of the users needs) or the safer (but requiring more action from all users) option of having them always choose.

The key point is to *monitor the usage and let the actual user data drive the design*.

Pre-selecting 'Open' as an option, may be a great idea or a terrible one. It may be that some users never change it and some change it all the time. Perhaps the best approach is to enable users to set their own defaults.

Until you actually monitor usage and make a data-drive user-centric decision, the opinions of those who say "do" and those who say "don't" more or less cancel each other out.

Comment: The choice was definitly made to have the default be neither choice for the reason of not assuming. However, I still think that it is implied that they would want open if they began entering open or close times.

Comment: I am working out a usability test with several clients to get a feel for the usage of the section so hard data will be coming. Just curious if that scenario had been looked at before. I couldn't find anything definite in searching although a lot of studies point to easing form usage by filling out certain things like having the user enter the zip code which populates city and state.